# Setting rightview on subclass of UITextField after initialization

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I try to set the `rightView` after UITextField initialized, but it gets `nil`. Here's my class:

```
class MyTextField: UITextField, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {  
    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        prepare()
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        prepare()
    }

    public convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    open private(set) var errorUIImageView = UIImageView(image: (resourceName: "ic_error_red"))

    open func prepare() {
        print("prepare")
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("handleTap:")))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tap.delegate = self
        errorUIImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        errorUIImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        self.rightView = errorUIImageView // setting the rightView here
    }

    @IBInspectable
    open var detail: String? {
        get {
            return detailLabel.text
        }
        set(value) {
            detailLabel.text = value
            if let v: String = value {
                self.rightViewMode = .always

                if self.rightView == nil {
                    print("nil") // this line is reached!
                }
            }
            else {
                self.rightViewMode = .never;
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    open var detailColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            if let v: String = detailLabel.text {
                detailLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: v, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: detailColor])
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    open private(set) lazy var detailLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)

    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        print("tapped")
    }
}
```

Most of the code is taken from [Material](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material)

Comment: I tried out this code and it works perfectly for me.  Are you sure you are not setting the rightView to nil from somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe you need to update your `storyboard`?

Comment: @CarienvanZyl Yes, I'm sure. I moved `self.rightView = errorUIImageView` to `draw` method and it's working. Still don't know whats the problem though.

Comment: @Aerows Could you explain more? What should I update in storyboard?

Comment: @CarienvanZyl check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you `edited` your implementation after displaying it for the first time in `interface builder`, you might have to **refresh** all views.

[image]

Comment: 'Refresh All Views' is disabled on my Xcode (tried selecting many things and nothing changed), but `Automatically Refresh Views` is enabled. I tried cleaning and rebuilding with no luck.